# ValueError: Cannot alter field Schedule.Swimming.player into Schedule.Swimming.player (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields)

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Match(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField('my date')
    time = models.TimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField(null = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=CATEGORY_CHOICES[0][0])
    place = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    game_status = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True) #completed or not

    # Foreign Keys
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True   

 class Swimming(Match):
        time = models.TimeField(null=True)
        player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name='player_swimming')
        game_level = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES) # like semi-final, final etc
        game_specific = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True, choices=EVENT_CHOICES) #like Men's Shot Put or Men's Triple Jump etc

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.game_level)
```

This is my initial model *Swimming* which is extended from base class *Match*. Now i want to add one intermediate model **PlayerSwimming** to *Swimming* model.Now it is stuck during the makemigration phase. I have tried all the possibilities like first deleting the migration and adding again ,commenting and migrate and then uncommenting it and migrate again. Help me! The new model is:

```
class Swimming(Match):


    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='PlayerSwimming')
    game_level = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES) # like semi-final, final etc
    game_specific = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True, choices=EVENT_CHOICES) #like Men's Shot Put or Men's Triple Jump etc


    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.category) + "  " + str(self.date))


class PlayerSwimming(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    swimming = models.ForeignKey(Swimming, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    time = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True, choices=MEDAL_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.player)
        # return str(self.swimming) + str(" ") + str(self.player)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time']
```

Comment: You don't need a `Player` and a `Swimming` on the `PlayerSwimming` model, since the `Swimming` model has those, and is joined to the `PlayerSwimming`. Are you sure you really need `PlayerSwimming`?

Comment: Hey @RobL ! I need that intermediate model because i have to store individual player info like time and medal, which i cannot do in "Swimming" model alone, because its a ManyToManyField in Player field of "Swimming".

Comment: Then why do you have a `Player` on `Swimming`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have too many keys. This should give you what you want.

```
class Swimming(Match):
    game_level = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
    game_specific = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=EVENT_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.category) + "  " + str(self.date))


class PlayerSwimming(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    swimming = models.ForeignKey(Swimming, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    time = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True, choices=MEDAL_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.player)
        # return str(self.swimming) + str(" ") + str(self.player)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time']
```